# Strange entry in dnsmasq log

Tags: dns

In Pihole dashboard I found this error:

```
Maximum number of concurrent DNS queries reached (max: 150)
```

Checking the pihole logs, at that time, I found several lines like this :

```
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: query[A] safebrowsing.brave.com from 192.168.88.204
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: forwarded safebrowsing.brave.com to 149.112.112.112
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: query[A] safebrowsing.brave.com.pippo.it from 192.168.88.204
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: forwarded safebrowsing.brave.com.pippo.it to 192.168.88.10
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: query[AAAA] safebrowsing.brave.com from 192.168.88.204
Apr 14 00:12:39 dnsmasq[280]: forwarded safebrowsing.brave.com to 149.112.112.112
```

Here:

- `pippo.it` is my local home domain,
- `192.168.88.204` is my pc's IP, running Linux Manjaro,
- `192.168.88.10` is a conditional forwarding DNS Server for `pippo.it`,
- `192.168.88.11` is `Pihole`,
- `149.112.112.112` is the `upstream (ISP) DNS serve`.

**Why do you think my local domain is added in those specific queries at that time?**

The same queries to the same external domain made hours later are made regularly without adding the local domain!

Any ideas?